# bash: if statement with multiple checks

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

In my bash script I need to check if the first CLI is defined and the second one is an existing file

Here is what I have:

```
if [!$2] && [! -f $1 ]; then
    ....
fi
```

So $2 should exist (string) and $1 should be the existing file on the filesystem!
Any suggestions ?

Comment: Yes, add spaces around brackets to make it work --> `if [ ! -f "$1" ]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by suggestions you mean *what do I need to make it work*, then what you need to do is to add spaces around brackets. Also it is good to quote the variables:

```
if [ -n "$2" ] && [ ! -f "$1" ]; then
   ...
fi
```

From `man test`:

> **-n STRING**
>
> the length of STRING is nonzero